# No funciona prompt en javascript

Tags: javascript, prompt

no me funciona el prompt no entiendo por qué

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El link del script va en el Body. La direccion de ese script esta dentro de la misma carpeta asique dierctamente se lo llama como "entreno.js" <script src="entreno.js"></script> sin una ruta adeltante. se pone en la ultima linea del body para que cargue todo el html y luego los scripts

Comment: Gracias  por responder , mira he actualizado las imagenes , no me ha funcionado , no salta la alerta ni los prompt

Comment: El código no va como imágenes. Nadie te va a responder con imágenes. Los errores pueden estar en detalles que no se ven en imágenes; desde el celular es imposible leer tu código. Edita tu pregunta y usa texto, por favor

Comment: que te muestra la consola ?

Comment: Lo correcto es `<script src="entreno.js"></script>`, tienes el src dentro de la etiqueta.

Comment: no sale nada :S

Comment: De nuevo: el código no va como imágenes. Ponlo _como texto, con formato_. De hecho, puedes crear un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`). No todos pueden ver las imágenes, ¡mucho menos se puede depurar el código de una imagen!

Comment: he actualizado con foto

Answer (score 1):

No funciona porque los scripts no se colocan así, se pone una etiqueta script, la cual hará referencia a tu archivo de JavaScript. De la siguiente forma:

```html
<script src="entreno.js"></script>
```

Esta etiqueta se suele poner dentro del `<body></body>`, hasta la parte del fondo, para que los componentes alcancen a cargar y no haya errores si este modifica componentes del documento.
Si el fichero que estar referenciando no se encuentra en una carpeta hija, no teines que poner el nombre de la carpeta, solo el nombre del mismo.

Ademas, por lo que veo en tu codigo de JavaScript, el alert no se llama de esa manera, ya que no es un valor, es una funcion, por lo que en lugar de poner `alert = 'hola';` debe ponerse

```javascript
alert('hola');
```

Comment: Gracias  por responder , mira he actualizado las imagenes , no me ha funcionado , no salta la alerta ni los prompt